# hasOne or BelongsTo in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables: `Photos` and `ProductPhotos` where `ProductPhotos` is:

```
ProductPhotos
_______________
product_id | photo_id
```

And `Photos` is:

```
Photos
_______________
id | photo
```

Does it mean that relation beetween  `ProductPhotos -> Photos` as `belongsTo` or `hasOne` yet?

Cause `photo_id` is foreign key, I guess it is `belogsTo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A belongsTo is used to define inverse of the relationship for both hasOne (One to One) and has Many (One to Many) relationship. It would not be possible to tell the relationship with foreign key. You need to define relationship in your relevant model.

In your case, relations can be

1. ProductPhotos belongsTo Products
2. Products can have hasOne or hasMany relationship with productPhotos. Depends on the relationship defined on the Product Model

You can have detail understanding on relationship on laravel Docs [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

I would set up the relationships with 
photos->hasOne->ProductPhotos->belongsTo->Products
Products->hasMany->ProductPhotos->belongsTo->Photos

This will allow for the use of Associate & Disassociate as well as the hasManyThrough relationship

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

This will also depend on your use of the images of the products

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

In this scenario it implies that you have a Products table, so your relationship seems to be from many to many.

Use in both tables:

```
belongsToMany
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I dont think so, cause I have intermediate table ProductPhoto that contains all photos links

Comment: So in table ProductPhoto that contains all photos links, that you use belongsToMany, as in table Photos, where you reference the ProductPhotos table